# Redirect a page with PHP and send a JSON string to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, xmlhttprequest

Right now I have a php file that recieves a string from a search bar on page1 of my website. It queries the data bases and creates a JSON string of results. I can then use PHP to redirect my website to page2 (The search results page). How can I receive that JSON string in the Javascript of page2?

Comment: Please [edit in](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20186455/edit) your current code.

Comment: I am just looking for a general method at the moment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

First you need a PHP file that will encode json code . Make a file like this:

```
http://localhost/project/myjs.php

<?php
    $arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);

    echo json_encode($arr); 
?>
```

Then your JavaScript (in this example I use jQuery):

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/project/myjs.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

This should be a start to get PHP arrays in to your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect browser to another page you have to use `header` function

```php
header:('Location: http://example.com/page2.php');
```

You can store data in `$_SESSION` array between pages like that:

**page1.php**

```php
session_start();
$_SESSION['array'] = array('foo'=>$bar);
```

**page2.php**

```php
session_start();
echo json_encode($_SESSION['array']);
```

Answer (score 0):

page1.php:

```
<?php
$my_array = array('foo'=>$bar);
$json_data = json_encode($my_array);
header:('Location: http://example.com/page2.php?data='.$json_data);
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
$data_get = $_REQUEST['data'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var mydata =<?php echo $data_get; ?>;
</script>
```